# Installers don't work from my Ubuntu Software

Tags: software-center

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Each and every time I try installing some software such as Star UML, the Software Center launches installation and then freezes and that's all about it. But when I install using my terminal everything works well. The only problem I have with this is that it is sometimes boring to have to type the commands in the terminal just for a minor installation of a software package.

I have taken a look at questions here that try to relate to this topic but they don't offer me the required solution. Is there a way I can get rid of this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say 'installer' what program are you using for this? What does the icon look like?

Comment: @PaulBenson, please read the question again. I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, well Software Center has always been a bit glitchy in 16.04. Even when you delete an App, it often still shows as present until a reboot. Best thing is to use Synaptic (the GUI for apt-get), or the Terminal for installing software.

Comment: Let me try Synaptic since I have been using the Terminal option.

Comment: Please, guys, I still don't have a response or solution to this problem. Thanks.